# Seeking a simple Android example to connect to Spring websocket (using STOMP and sockjs)

Tags: android, spring, websocket, stomp

I want to create a simple Android app (websocket client) which will connect to websocket server.

I have created websocket server using spring boot with STOMP and I am successfully able to connect, subscribe and send messages to it using JavaScript client but I want to do the same things using an Android application.

**My Spring boot websocket configuration is:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends 
AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
    stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/sowebsocket")
            .addInterceptors(new HttpHandshakeInterceptor())
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS();
}
```

**My JavaScript client code:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sockjs-client/1.3.0/sockjs.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.js"></script>

<script> 

    var stompClient = null;

    function connect() {
        var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/sowebsocket');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
            stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/user.personal', function (greeting) {
                showGreeting(greeting.body.messageText);
            });
        });
    }

    function disconnect() {
        if (stompClient !== null) {
            stompClient.disconnect();
        }
        setConnected(false);
        console.log("Disconnected");
    }

    $(function () {
        connect();
    )};

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found related example on https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid. Thanks to Nickolay Savchenko (NaikSoftware)